# How to ensure Executor service does process data from StateStore without being blocked forever

Tags: multithreading, apache-kafka-streams, executorservice, rocksdb

I have a Kafka streams based application (using low-level API), in brief, it does the following:

Stream process (the one having `process()` method)

- Reads data from Kafka topic
- Puts the data into `StateStore` (backed by `RocksDB`)

The Stream processor spawns a thread during initialization(in init() method, call it worker thread):

- The worker thread is executor service and awakes every 1 minute
- Reads data from the same StateStore and then does the processing.

I have a requirement, in which this Worker executor service needs to be awoken every 2 hours (instead of minutes).

Since stream thread is doing read/write on the same StateStore from which Worker executor service would be trying to do read/write, how do I ensure that the Worker thread does do work without being blocked forever; as chances are, stream thread would be holding lock/monitor on StateStore.

Can anyone provide some inputs on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I believe RocksDB API is thread-safe so it shouldn't be a problem.

As an aside, You can consider using [Punctuator](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/Punctuator.html) instead of spawning a different thread. The punctuator is invoked by the Stream Thread, so it will be a single thread.